# NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest not blocking

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsurlconnection, nsoperation

I'm calling `NSURLConnection` -`sendSynchronousRequest` in NSOperation, but the method returns immediately. I would expect it to block the operation until all data is received. Is this a misunderstanding on my part?

Comment: can you provide more info, preferably with code?

Comment: Give us your NSOperation code (especially the -main method) to see what you're actually doing.

Answer (score 0):

set the delegate of the NSURLConnection object to self
`NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];`
and then implement the connectionDidFinishLoading methode
`-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
//your code
}`